# Why filename is converted to lower case when drag and drop into Clearcase explorer?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

One of my colleague reported a peculiar problem in clearcase. (It is a base clearcase view.)

When he drag and drop a file from windows explorer to clearcase explorer, the filename is automatically converted to lowercase letters.

It is a headache for him as he has to change them manually again.

I tried in my clearcase explorer and i did not find that behavior. I tried in options but i was not able to find any good resolution.

Has any one faced this and tackled this? If so , Please help me with the steps to resolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That might be because you didn't activate this option "**Case Preserving**" (for dynamic views, using MVFS):

(Those options can be found in `ClearCase Home Base -- or type`clearhomebase`-- , Administration tab, Control Panel`, reminds us [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10410/kevin-haines) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10410/kevin-haines))

[image: case insensitive]

Note: a reboot might be needed for the option to be applied.

With **Case Preserving**, no case conversion should take place.
See more on:

- "[Before setting case-sensitivity options in dynamic views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_mvfs/before_set_case_sens_dyn.htm)"

> [...] This does not happen for a view-private object that you create in a VOB namespace **if you clear Case Preserving (the default)**.
>   In this case, **the MVFS converts the name to lowercase (that is, util.obj) when it creates the file**.

- "[About case-sensitivity](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_case_sensitivity.htm)". More generally (and this isn't your issue here), avoid having two files with the same name and different case. Windows won't support it well.

Comment: For reference, this can be found via the ClearCase Home Base, Administration tab, Control Panel (well, it is under ClearCase 7.1.1.0)

Comment: @KevinHaines good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.